# Wrong field value in Django FileField

Tags: python, django

There are models:

```py
class DataFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text='Краткое наименование данных',
        verbose_name = 'Наименование'
        )
    
    file = models.FileField(upload_to ='data/', 
                            verbose_name = 'Файл данных',
                            unique=True)

....

class Map(models.Model): 
..........
    data_file = models.ForeignKey(
        DataFile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name = 'Файл данных',
        to_field='file'

        )
..........
```

I have an object of class Map. However, when referring to him

```py
obj.get().data_file.file.path
```

or

```py
obj.get().data_file.file
```

its behavior is different for django-shell and actual work. For Django-shell, a manual request gives the full path, which is what I need (stored in the 'file' field of the DataFile class). But in real work it outputs the value of the 'title' field of the DataFile class).

I need the output to be exactly the full path to the file, i.e. what is stored in the file field.

Comment: `.file` will return a `FieldFile`, and `str(..)` will retrieve the value stored in the database, whereas `.file.path` is the path of the file on the OS.

Comment: Everything works great in Django-shell. Problem during normal operation. file.path returns the value of my 'title' field (ex. 'World map') instead 'file' field of `/home/user/.../world_map.csv`

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the primary key, but why then does everything work in the Django-shell?

Comment: Are you sure you are not printing `obj.get().data_file` for example. Since the shell works exactly the same way as runserver, it is not possible that for the *same* attribute for the *same* object it produces a different result.

Comment: Here is the output from my django-shell:
`In [39]: obj.get (). Data_file
Out [39]: <DataFile: Russia economy> `.
This is also displayed during normal operation in the request `obj.get (). Data_file.file.path`

Comment: But in django-shell the request is `obj.get (). Data_file.file.path` gives the correct path 'home / ....'

Comment: actually instead of `obj.get (). data_file.file.path` 'I have `obj.get (). Data_file.title`

Comment: If you prints `type(obj.get (). data_file.file)` ?